# Help on a tough summation from Rudin?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation

I'm having a tough time deriving (4) from the bracketed expression in (3) shown in the photo.  I've been futzing with partial sums of geometric series and binomial expansions for a while now with no luck.  Anyone have an idea on this one? (This is from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis btw...)

[image: Proof from Rudin]

Comment: Two things: first, $z^n - w^n = (z-w)(z^{n-1} + z^{n-2}w + \cdots + w^{n-1})$; second, the $k$'s will basically cancel if you expand (4) as a telescoping sum (there are other derivations). Maybe try the $n=3$ case to see these in action.

Comment: @JSwanson: Thank you as well.  I appreciate the helpful nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression on the right of (3) can be transformed into
\begin{align}
\frac{z^n-w^n}{z-w}-nw^{n-1}&=z^{n-1}\frac{1-\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^{n}}{1-\frac{w}{z}}-nw^{n-1}=\\
&=z^{n-1}\left[1+\frac{w}{z}+\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^{2}+\ldots+\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^{n-1}\right]-nw^{n-1}=\\
&=\left(z^{n-1}+wz^{n-2}+w^2z^{n-3}+\ldots+w^{n-1}\right)-nw^{n-1}.
\end{align}
On the other hand, (4) may be rewritten as
\begin{align}
(z-w)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kw^{k-1}z^{n-k-1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kw^{k-1}z^{n-k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kw^{k}z^{n-k-1}=\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kw^{k-1}z^{n-k}-\sum_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)w^{k-1}z^{n-k}=\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kw^{k-1}z^{n-k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)w^{k-1}z^{n-k}=\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w^{k-1}z^{n-k}-(n-1)\cdot w^{n-1}\cdot z^{n-n}=\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w^{k-1}z^{n-k}-(n-1) w^{n-1}.
\end{align}
Can you see that both expressions coincide?

Comment: Oh man.. That was a righteous calculation. Yeah I'm with you.  I can see they're the same.  The shifting of the index on the sum threw me off.  Thanks for the help!